# Lists within dataframes python

Tags: python, list, dataframe, twitter

I am working with tweets and I have a dataframe with lists of string elements:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([('parrot', [], 'tweet'),   
                    ('lion',  ["covid"], 'tweet'),  
                    ('monkey', ["covid", "gripe"] , 'tweet')],  
                  columns=('name_user', 'hashtags', 'full_text'))
```

I want to generate filters based on the elements inside the column "hashtags".

Is there a way to extract all the lists that are empty or all the ones that have content?

I would like to extract something like this:

```
name_user         hashtag         
parrot             []
```

or like this:

```
name_user         hashtag         
lion              ["covid"]   
monkey            ["covid", "gripe"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Empty ones:

```
df[df['hashtags'].apply(lambda x: len(x)) == 0]
```

Non-empty ones:

```
df[df['hashtags'].apply(lambda x: len(x)) != 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try `astype(bool)`:

```
print(df.loc[df['hashtags'].astype(bool)])
```

Output:

```
  name_user        hashtags full_text
1      lion         [covid]     tweet
2    monkey  [covid, gripe]     tweet
```

For empty lists:

```
print(df.loc[~df['hashtags'].astype(bool)])
```

Output:

```
name_user hashtags full_text
0    parrot       []     tweet
```